# boostrap4 data-toggle in navbar is now working

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap v4.3.1 But My data-toggle collapse not working.
Here is image which is boostrap v3.4.1 sidebar  working..

[image]

When i use bootstrap v4.3.1, it does not showing data-toggle collapse.I have use bellow like code..

```
  <nav id="sidebar">

        <div class="dropdown-divider devider-sidbar-color"></div>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#100" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Admin Setup
                <i  class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i></a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="100">
                <li><a href="#">Staff Registration</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Taxt Setup</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Taxt Setup</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Right Setup</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <div class="dropdown-divider devider-sidbar-color"></div>
    </nav>
```

How to work above like image in latest boostrap , please help me

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap collapse wont work if the id is int or number like 100 or 200 if you want it to work you need to put id like word here is an example

```
  <nav id="sidebar">

    <div class="dropdown-divider devider-sidbar-color"></div>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#hi" data-toggle="collapse" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">Admin Setup</a>
        <ul class="collapse" id="hi">
            <li><a href="#">Staff Registration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Taxt Setup</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Taxt Setup</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">User Right Setup</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    <div class="dropdown-divider devider-sidbar-color"></div>
</nav>
```